# Getting specific part of list elemnt

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I have this list `[c1=2*3,c2=5*1,c3=1*1]` and i want to create a new list with just the 3rd element of each element of the list, so something like this `[2,5,1]`. I'm using nth0 to access each of the elements of the list but from there i can't progress much further. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you defining the "elements" of the items in your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I assume that the list is composed by elements of the form `(A = B * C)` and that you want to filter only the component `B` of each one of them. In this case, a possible solution is as follows:

```
filter([], []).
filter([(_ = B * _)|Xs], [B|Ys]) :- filter(Xs, Ys).
```

Example:

```
?- filter([c1=2*3, c2=5*1, c3=1*1], L).
L = [2, 5, 1].
```